# Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function [PRELOADER]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to add a simple preloader to my website and I get this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`

HTML index.html

```
<html class="js">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="preloader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS style.css

```
.js div#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #143441 url('assets/img/loader.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

This only shows a gif that is constantly rotating and after the end of loading..

Comment: check the network tab of your developer tools to verify that your JQuery script reference is resolving properly.

Comment: I now got this in console `jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:23)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I searched a little and found a solution. The problem is in `.load` event aliase, it needs to be replaced `.on`

Example:

`$(window).load(function(){...});`

becomes:

`$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});`